# How to bend a cylinder in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, trigonometry

How would you arc or bend a cylinder type geometry (that has distortion) in three.js?

Id like to specify these parameters:

- **Bend Start** - at what percent of the cylinder's height the bend starts
- **Bend End** - at what percent of the cylinder's height the bend ends
- **Angle** - how strong the bend is

  [image: parameters]

I'll be controlling them with sliders.  My cylinder shape is created from an extrusion of a bezier curve that the user draws (extension of geometry class in three.js).

I'd also like to be able to layer several bend effects on top of each other.  So a bend could affect the first part, then a second bend could bend the cylinder back.

I'm not the best at math, so that's why i'm asking for tips or formulas that could do this in three.js.  I'm thinking maybe i could put a line at the center axis then bend that with a bezier curve.  From there i could use the lines position to influence the vertices of the cylinder.  Does this sound like a good idea?

Comment: Have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41470597/4045502).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smoothly connecting circle centers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178181/smoothly-connecting-circle-centers)

Comment: See the duplicate [Smoothly connecting circle centers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178181/smoothly-connecting-circle-centers) if you want something more see [Apply Rotation to Cylinder based on Tube Ending Normal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39674497/2521214)

Comment: @Spektre, i don't think that post will help because my shape is distorted.  Any idea how to curve distorted geometries?

Comment: @Spektre this is a codepen with a shape like what I'm trying to bend.  But instead of smooth arc, trying to control bend more  https://codepen.io/funianrun/pen/QzQQJB

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea I agree in such case its not exact duplicate (but very similar) I retracted my Close Vote and added answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is cut your mesh into slices and convert each slice in the same manner as I do the circles in here:

- [Smoothly connecting circle centers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178181/smoothly-connecting-circle-centers)

That is done like this:

1. **straight form coordinate system**

   Create position `P0` and 3 basis vectors `X0,Y0,Z0` representing coordinates of the mesh in straight form. Let assume the `Z0` is the axis you want to bend.

   [image: P0X0Y0Z0]
2. **convert each vertex into `P0,X0,Y0,Z0` local coordinates**

   so any point `P` is transformed into:

   ```
   P.x' = dot( P-P0 , X0 )
   P.y' = dot( P-P0 , Y0 )
   P.z' = dot( P-P0 , Z0 )
   ```
3. **create bend form coordinate system `P1,X1,Y1,Z1`**

   so simply based on the `P.z'` used as a parameter (arclength on the bended shape) compute the angle of the bended arc and rotate `X0,Y0,Z0` into `X1,Y1,Z1` if the bending is around `X` then `X1 = X0` and you need to rotate just the other two vectors.

   [image: P1X1Y1Z1]
4. **convert P' into bended form P''**

   simply do this:

   ```
   P'' = P1 + P.x'*X1 + P.y'*Y1
   ```

   now `P''` is the final vertex of your shape. So you can render you mesh after converting all of its points. As you can see we do not need the `P.z` ... as its encoded in the `P1` position already. So also no real need to compute the `Z1` basis vector too.

**[Notes]**

**Beware that too big bends can corrupt your mesh topology** if you bend too much then you can self intersect the slices between each other.

Also all the corresponding basis vectors should have the same size Ideally unit.

The rotation of `Y0 -> Y1` is simple 2D problem and if `Y0=(0,1,0)` its even simpler just point on circle `Y1=(cos(a),sin(a),0)` ... so you do not even need the 2D rotation formula.

**[Edit1] C++/GL example**

I was curious so I take a generated tube with sinus screw and bend it... This is the result:

[image: preview]

I rendered both straight and bended meshes for visual comparison. The red point is the bend center and the line connects it to `P0`.  I chose `P0,X0,Y0,Z0` to match unit matrix. The example is transformed so it matches the images in this question (in un-animated state). Here the **C++/GL** code I done this with:

The mesh and bending **zavit.h**:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- tube with sinus screw -------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int ca=20;
const int cb=50;
const float r0=0.3;
const float r1=0.35;
const float l1=2.0;
const float nz=5.0;
vec3 pnt0[ca][cb];  // straight mesh
vec3 nor0[ca][cb];
vec2 txr0[ca][cb];
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
vec3 pnt1[ca][cb];  // bended mesh
vec3 nor1[ca][cb];
vec2 txr1[ca][cb];
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void obj0_init()    // sin screw
    {
    int     i,j,i0,j0;
    float   a,b,l,da,db,dl,r,s,c,tx,ty;
    float   dtx=1.0/float(ca-1),dty=1.0/float(cb-1);
    vec3    u,v;
    // pnt,txr
    da=2.0*M_PI/float(ca-1);
    db=nz*2.0*M_PI/float(cb);
    dl=l1/float(cb);
    for (a=0.0,tx=0.0,i=0;i<ca;i++,a+=da,tx+=dtx)
        {
        s=sin(a);
        c=cos(a);
        for (l=-0.5*l1,b=0,ty=0.0,j=0;j<cb;j++,b+=db,l+=dl,ty+=dty)
            {
            r=r0+((r1-r0)*cos(a+b));
            pnt0[i][j].x=r*c;
            pnt0[i][j].y=r*s;
            pnt0[i][j].z=l;
            txr0[i][j].x=tx;
            txr0[i][j].y=ty;
            }
        }
    // nor
    for (i0=ca-2,i=0;i<ca;i0=i,i++)
     for (j0=cb-1,j=0;j<cb;j0=j,j++)
        {
        u=pnt0[i][j]-pnt0[i0][j];
        v=pnt0[i][j]-pnt0[i][j0];
        nor0[i][j]=normalize(cross(v,u));
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void obj1_bend(vec3 center) // bend obj0 -> obj1 ... pc center, P0,X0,Y0,Z0 = unit matrix
    {
    int i,j,i0,j0;
    float a,r;
    vec3 p,p1,x1,y1,u,v;
    // bend pnt, copy txr
    r=length(center);
    for (i=0;i<ca;i++)
     for (j=0;j<cb;j++)
        {
        p=pnt0[i][j];               // p' = p

        a=p.z/r;                    // arc length -> angle [rad]
        p1=center;                  // p1 point on circleYZ (bending around X)
        p1.y-=r*cos(a);
        p1.z-=r*sin(a);
        x1=vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0);       // basis vectors
        y1=vec3(0.0,cos(a),sin(a));

        p=p1+(p.x*x1)+(p.y*y1);     // p''

        pnt1[i][j]=p;
        txr1[i][j]=txr0[i][j];
        }
    // nor
    for (i0=ca-2,i=0;i<ca;i0=i,i++)
     for (j0=cb-1,j=0;j<cb;j0=j,j++)
        {
        u=pnt1[i][j]-pnt1[i0][j];
        v=pnt1[i][j]-pnt1[i][j0];
        nor1[i][j]=normalize(cross(v,u));
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void obj0_draw()
    {
    int i,j;
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
    for (i=0;i<ca-1;i++)
        {
        glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
        for (j=0;j<cb;j++)
            {
            glTexCoord2fv(txr0[i+1][j].dat);
            glNormal3fv  (nor0[i+1][j].dat);
            glVertex3fv  (pnt0[i+1][j].dat);
            glTexCoord2fv(txr0[i  ][j].dat);
            glNormal3fv  (nor0[i  ][j].dat);
            glVertex3fv  (pnt0[i  ][j].dat);
            }
        glEnd();
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void obj1_draw()
    {
    int i,j;
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
    for (i=0;i<ca-1;i++)
        {
        glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
        for (j=0;j<cb;j++)
            {
            glTexCoord2fv(txr1[i+1][j].dat);
            glNormal3fv  (nor1[i+1][j].dat);
            glVertex3fv  (pnt1[i+1][j].dat);
            glTexCoord2fv(txr1[i  ][j].dat);
            glNormal3fv  (nor1[i  ][j].dat);
            glVertex3fv  (pnt1[i  ][j].dat);
            }
        glEnd();
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the main **VCL** app code (ignore the **VCL** stuff just port/use what you need):

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "gl_simple.h"
double divide(double a,double b){ if (fabs(b)<1e-10) return 0.0; return a/b; }
#include "GLSL_math.h"
#include "zavit.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
vec3 center=vec3(0.0,1.7,0.0);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    float aspect=float(xs)/float(ys);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0/aspect,aspect,0.1,100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-5.5);
    glRotatef(80.0,1.0,0.0,0.0);        // Z+ up slightly forw
    static float ang=0.0; ang+=5.0;
    glRotatef(45.0+ang,0.0,0.0,1.0);    // X+ right forw, Y+ left forw, + animation rotation around up

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    // original mesh
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-0.7,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    obj0_draw();
    glPopMatrix();

    // bended mesh
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(+0.7,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    obj1_draw();


    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glPointSize(10.0);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3fv(center.dat);    // bending center
    glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);    // P0
    glEnd();
    glPointSize(1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3fv(center.dat);
    glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glEnd();

/*
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0); glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,0.0); glVertex3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0); glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,0.0); glVertex3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0); glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,0.0); glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glEnd();
*/
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    gl_init(Handle);
    obj0_init();
    obj1_bend(center);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_resize(ClientWidth,ClientHeight);
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For **OpenGL** I am using **GLEW** and mine **gl_simple.h** which can be found here:

- [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)

the **GLSL_math.h** is mine vector math mimicking **GLSL** math but you can use any vector math... You just need `+,-,dot,cross,normalize,length` which are all basic operations and you can code it on your own too or use **GLM** or whatever...

**[Edit2] some more simplification and repeatability**

Well according to your sketch and late comments It will not work with heights. Instead use arc-lengths (height in straight form mesh) as parameters. After some more taught I ended up with this:

[image: new approach]

To simplify things I added for each slice a center point, main axis direction and slice length. That enables much simpler computations ... Here preview of applied 45 deg bend twice (+45 and -45):

[image: double bend]

The RGB lines are global coordinate system for the bended mesh render, yellowish is the mesh center axis + bending range of last bend for debug and red is the last bend center.

**here new C++ code `zavit.h`:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- tube with sinus screw -------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/54050883/2521214
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int   ca= 20;     // points per slice
const int   cb=100;     // slices
const float r0=  0.3;   // minor screw radius
const float r1=  0.35;  // major screw radius
const float l1=  4.0;   // tube length
const float nz= 10.0;   // screws
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
vec3 bend_pc; int bend_j0,bend_j1;  // just for debug draw
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// straight mesh
vec3 pnt0[ca][cb];  // vertex
vec3 nor0[ca][cb];  // normal
vec2 txr0[ca][cb];  // texcoord
vec3 mid0[cb];      // slice center
vec3 dir0[cb];      // slice central axis (normalized)
float len0[cb];     // slice arclength position
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// bended mesh
vec3 pnt1[ca][cb];  // vertex
vec3 nor1[ca][cb];  // normal
vec2 txr1[ca][cb];  // texcoord
vec3 mid1[cb];      // slice center
vec3 dir1[cb];      // slice central axis (normalized)
float len1[cb];     // slice arclength position
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void obj0_init()    // sin screw
    {
    int     i,j,i0,j0;
    float   a,b,l,da,db,dl,r,s,c,tx,ty;
    float   dtx=1.0/float(ca-1),dty=1.0/float(cb-1);
    vec3    u,v;
    // pnt,txr
    da=2.0*M_PI/float(ca-1);
    db=nz*2.0*M_PI/float(cb);
    dl=l1/float(cb);
    for (a=0.0,tx=0.0,i=0;i<ca;i++,a+=da,tx+=dtx)
        {
        s=sin(a);
        c=cos(a);
        for (l=-0.5*l1,b=0,ty=0.0,j=0;j<cb;j++,b+=db,l+=dl,ty+=dty)
            {
            r=r0+((r1-r0)*cos(a+b));
            pnt0[i][j].x=r*c;
            pnt0[i][j].y=r*s;
            pnt0[i][j].z=l;
            txr0[i][j].x=tx;
            txr0[i][j].y=ty;
            }
        }
    // mid,dir
    for (l=0.0,j=0;j<cb;j++,l+=dl)
        {
        mid0[j]=vec3(0.0,0.0, l-(0.5*l1));
        dir0[j]=vec3(0.0,0.0,dl);
        len0[j]=l;
        }
    // nor
    for (i0=ca-2,i=0;i<ca;i0=i,i++)
     for (j0=cb-1,j=0;j<cb;j0=j,j++)
        {
        u=pnt0[i][j]-pnt0[i0][j];
        v=pnt0[i][j]-pnt0[i][j0];
        nor0[i][j]=normalize(cross(u,v));
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void obj1_copy()    // obj1 = obj0
    {
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<ca;i++)
     for (j=0;j<cb;j++)
        {
        pnt1[i][j]=pnt0[i][j];
        txr1[i][j]=txr0[i][j];
        nor1[i][j]=nor0[i][j];
        }
    for (j=0;j<cb;j++)
        {
        mid1[j]=mid0[j];
        dir1[j]=dir0[j];
        len1[j]=len0[j];
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
vec3 rotatex(vec3 p,vec3 p0,float a)
    {
    vec3 q; p-=p0;
    q.z=+(p.z*cos(a))+(p.y*sin(a));
    q.y=-(p.z*sin(a))+(p.y*cos(a));
    q.x=p.x;
    return q+p0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
vec3 rotatey(vec3 p,vec3 p0,float a)
    {
    vec3 q; p-=p0;
    q.x=+(p.x*cos(a))+(p.z*sin(a));
    q.z=-(p.x*sin(a))+(p.z*cos(a));
    q.y=p.y;
    return q+p0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
vec3 rotatez(vec3 p,vec3 p0,float a)
    {
    vec3 q; p-=p0;
    q.x=+(p.x*cos(a))+(p.y*sin(a));
    q.y=-(p.x*sin(a))+(p.y*cos(a));
    q.z=p.z;
    return q+p0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void obj1_bendx(float l0,float l1,float ang)    // [units],[units],[rad] bend obj1 around x axis
    {
    int i,j,i0,j0,j1;
    float a,r,l;
    vec3 PC,p,u,v;
    vec3 P0,X0,Y0,Z0;
    // find start and end of bend
    for (j0= 0;(j0<cb)&&(len1[j0]<l0);j0++);
    for (j1=j0;(j1<cb)&&(len1[j1]<l1);j1++);
    if (j0>cb) return;          // no bend
    // coordinate system0
    P0=mid1[j0];
    Z0=normalize(dir1[j0]);
    X0=vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    Y0=cross(Z0,X0);
    X0=cross(Y0,Z0);
    // bend center
    r=(l1-l0)/ang;
    PC=P0-(Y0*r);
    r=fabs(r);
    // just for debug draw
    bend_pc=PC;
    bend_j0=j0;
    bend_j1=j1;
    // bend <l0,l1)
    for (j=j0;j<cb;j++)
        {
        // arc length -> angle [rad] and length correction
        if (j<j1)
            {
            a=ang*(len1[j]-l0)/(l1-l0);
            p=Z0*(len1[j]-l0);
            }
        else{
            a=ang;
            p=Z0*(l1-l0);
            }
        // transform system0 -> system1
        mid1[j]=rotatex(mid1[j]-p,PC,a);
        dir1[j]=rotatex(dir1[j],vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0),a);
        for (i=0;i<ca;i++) pnt1[i][j]=rotatex(pnt1[i][j]-p,PC,a);
        }
    // nor
    for (i0=ca-2,i=0;i<ca;i0=i,i++)
     for (j0=cb-1,j=0;j<cb;j0=j,j++)
        {
        u=pnt1[i][j]-pnt1[i0][j];
        v=pnt1[i][j]-pnt1[i][j0];
        nor1[i][j]=normalize(cross(u,v));
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void obj0_draw()
    {
    int i,j;
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    for (i=0;i<ca-1;i++)
        {
        glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
        for (j=0;j<cb;j++)
            {
            glTexCoord2fv(txr0[i+1][j].dat);
            glNormal3fv  (nor0[i+1][j].dat);
            glVertex3fv  (pnt0[i+1][j].dat);
            glTexCoord2fv(txr0[i  ][j].dat);
            glNormal3fv  (nor0[i  ][j].dat);
            glVertex3fv  (pnt0[i  ][j].dat);
            }
        glEnd();
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void obj1_draw()
    {
    int i,j;
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    for (i=0;i<ca-1;i++)
        {
        glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
        for (j=0;j<cb;j++)
            {
            glTexCoord2fv(txr1[i+1][j].dat);
            glNormal3fv  (nor1[i+1][j].dat);
            glVertex3fv  (pnt1[i+1][j].dat);
            glTexCoord2fv(txr1[i  ][j].dat);
            glNormal3fv  (nor1[i  ][j].dat);
            glVertex3fv  (pnt1[i  ][j].dat);
            }
        glEnd();
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**And the VCL window code:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "gl_simple.h"
double divide(double a,double b){ if (fabs(b)<1e-10) return 0.0; return a/b; }
#include "GLSL_math.h"
#include "zavit.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    float aspect=float(xs)/float(ys);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0/aspect,aspect,0.1,100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-5.5);
    glRotatef(-80.0,1.0,0.0,0.0);       // Z+ up slightly forw
    static float ang=0.0; ang+=5.0;
    glRotatef(45.0+ang,0.0,0.0,1.0);    // X+ right forw, Y+ left forw, + animation rotation around up

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    // [original mesh]
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-0.7,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    obj0_draw();
    glPopMatrix();

    // [bended mesh]
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(+0.7,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    obj1_draw();

    // debug draws
    int j;
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // global coordinates
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0); glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,0.0); glVertex3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0); glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,0.0); glVertex3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0); glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,0.0); glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glEnd();

    // mesh axis
    glLineWidth(2.0); glColor3f(0.9,0.6,0.1); glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for (j=0;j<bend_j0;j++) glVertex3fv(mid1[j].dat); if (j<cb){ glVertex3fv(mid1[j].dat); glVertex3fv(bend_pc.dat); }
    for (   ;j<bend_j1;j++) glVertex3fv(mid1[j].dat); if (j<cb){ glVertex3fv(mid1[j].dat); glVertex3fv(bend_pc.dat); }
    for (   ;j<cb     ;j++) glVertex3fv(mid1[j].dat);
    glEnd(); glLineWidth(1.0);
    // bending center
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glPointSize(10.0);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3fv(bend_pc.dat);
    glEnd();
    glPointSize(1.0);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    gl_init(Handle);
    obj0_init();
    obj1_copy();
    obj1_bendx(1.0,1.5,+45.0*M_PI/180.0);
    obj1_bendx(2.5,3.0,-45.0*M_PI/180.0);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_resize(ClientWidth,ClientHeight);
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Architecture is the same just the usage changed a bit now bend is applied directly on the mesh1 so it does not use the mesh0 anymore. So you need to copy mesh0 to mesh1 before use.

Also I exploited the fact that my mesh is sorted by arclength (`pnt1[angle][arclength]`) so I can process slices instead of raw points.

You can analogically write `bendy` and `bendz` functions just change the math a bit to match swapped axises ... If you do not need the original mesh then you can remove it now ...

**[Edit3] visual comparison with yours [code](https://codepen.io/funianrun/pen/OrYYwV)**

Its foreign language to me but similar to C/C++ so from a quick view:

1. **you use fixed `P0X0Y0Z0` which prevents you from applying bend more than once.**
2. **at line 155**

   ```
   var PC = new THREE.Vector3().copy(P0).sub(PC_X);
   ```

   it does not correspond to mine

   ```
   PC=P0-(Y0*r);
   ```

   you have different axis and no radius scale !!! in case your axises have different meaning then mine then you just swap the `X,Y,Z` accordingly but you still need to use the radius. This one is the position if the center of bending so if wrongly computed the bend is wrong too ... The axis used must be not the one around which the rotation is done and not height of the cylinder.
3. **at line 173**

   ```
   var p = new THREE.Vector3().copy(X0);
   p.multiplyScalar(slice_arc_length[j]-l0);
   ```

   I got:

   ```
   p=Z0*(len1[j]-l0);
   ```

   so clearly different axis again. You should use the height of cylinder axis... The same is also in the else at line 180.
4. **So if I see it right this is axis correspondence**

   ```
   mine    yours   meaning
   X0      Z0      bending rotation axis
   Y0      X0
   Z0      Y0      cylinder height
   ```
5. **line 182**

   you got:

   ```
   center_points[j] = rotatey(p,PC,a);
   center_vector[j] = rotatey(center_vector[j], new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0),a);
   for (var i=0; i<20; i++){ slices[i][j]= rotatey(slices[i][j].sub(p),PC,a); }
   ```

   I got:

   ```
   mid1[j]=rotatex(mid1[j]-p,PC,a);
   dir1[j]=rotatex(dir1[j],vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0),a);
   for (i=0;i<ca;i++) pnt1[i][j]=rotatex(pnt1[i][j]-p,PC,a);
   ```

   in case you `mid[]` is zero then still you need to use `-p`. Also you are rotating around `y` but from axis correspondence you are using in previous code you should rotate around `z` !!!

So you are wrongly setting the center of rotation, rotate around a wrong axis. Also check if you choose correctly the axises (they need to have the same meaning in your mesh).

**[Edit4] another comparison**

1. **line 105**

   ```
   var Z_Copy = new THREE.Vector3().copy(Z0);
   Z_Copy.multiplyScalar(r);
   var PC = new THREE.Vector3().copy(P0).sub(Z_Copy);
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   var X_Copy = new THREE.Vector3().copy(X0);
   X_Copy.multiplyScalar(r);
   var PC = new THREE.Vector3().copy(P0).sub(X_Copy);
   ```

   as you are rotating around `Z` so the center `PC` must be shifted in other axis... so `X`  that is why your bend is just shifted instead of rotated.

Looks like the rest of code should be OK but to be sure I would also render the `mid` and `dir` arrays to see if they are really where they should be in respect to the mesh (the yellow center line of mesh in my preview). Once the bend is working you should also port the `P0X0Y0Z0` computation from the `mid,dir` so you can apply the bend repetitively ...

If I swap to your axises it would be:

```
P0=mid1[j0];
Y0=normalize(dir1[j0]);
Z0=vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0);
X0=cross(Y0,Z0);
Y0=cross(Z0,X0);
```

**[edit5] another comparison**

You are doing the same mistakes again and again ... incorrectly re-writing equations so no brainner its not working right. This time:

1. **At line 186:**

   ```
   var point_temp = new THREE.Vector3().copy(slices[j][i]);
   ```

   you forgot to add the  `point_temp.sub(p);` that is the reason for distortion of shape and most likely also for the different rotation.
2. **your `rotatez`**

   is wrong as you got:

   ```
   p.x=+(p.x*Math.cos(a))+(p.y*Math.sin(a));
   p.y=+(p.x*Math.sin(a))+(p.y*Math.cos(a));
   p.z=p.z;
   ```

   and I got

   ```
   p.x=+(p.x*Math.cos(a))+(p.y*Math.sin(a));
   p.y=-(p.x*Math.sin(a))+(p.y*Math.cos(a));
   p.z=p.z;
   ```

   but anyway it also could be:

   ```
   p.x=+(p.x*Math.cos(a))-(p.y*Math.sin(a));
   p.y=+(p.x*Math.sin(a))+(p.y*Math.cos(a));
   p.z=p.z;
   ```

   try which one works I have my equations for `rotatex` tested not for `rotatez` ... the two versions just rotate in opposite directions so both are correct but the code can work correctly only with one.
3. **angular units**

   the bend of mid line (that one you got "right" in code) does not resemble rotation around `PC` it might be caused by **#2** but it also can be caused by wrong angle units. Do your `cos` and `sin` functions need `[deg]` or `[rad]` ? Currently all angles computed are in `[rad]`.

Comment: thanks for this explanation! In step 1, is P0 at the center of the geometry slice? or is it each vertex.  In step 2, does P.x' represent the x coordinate in local space? and you get it by taking a dot product of the vertex P-P0 and just the single x value X0?

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea `P0` is single point for whole mesh and yes it can be the center of the geometry too ..., `P1` is per each slice (P.z' coordinate),  In case your `X0,Y0,Z0` vectors match X,Y,Z coordinate axises then you do not need the dot product and simply use `P' = P-P0`. Inside the dot product of mine the `X0` is full vector so  `P.x' = dot( P-P0 , X0 ) = (P.x-P0.x)*X0.x + (P.y-P0.y)*X0.y + (P.z-P0.z)*X0.z`

Comment: okay I'm definitely understanding more how it works now, thank you.  I'm having a bit of trouble with step 3, though.  I outlined the steps i'm using here  https://pastebin.com/yjfM2xUC.  In it, I get P1.z' (arc length?) coming out as zero, so when i do the arc_length/radius I get 0 as the angle.  Is that the right formula to use to get the angle? S=Radius*Angle?  Also what formula would you use to rotate something like Z0 around P1 to turn it into Z1?  I think i'm very close now, thank you.

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea yes you right the slice where P.z' is zero is not bended ... the more distant in Z axis from `P0` the bigger the angle and also the bend ... btw if you are familiar with 4x4 transform matrices the 3x dot product stuff is single matrix multiplied by vector ... see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)... The rotation formula for Z0 is also 2D or just point on circle the same as for Y0 -> Y1 just using y and z coordinates `(sin(a),0,cos(a))` I think ... or `(cos(a),0,sin(a))` +/- some minus sign if needed

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea I added small C++/GL/VCL example it looks like mine approach works as expected ... heh took me 2hours to code it and edit the answer I am sluggishly slow signaling a desperate need for vacation ... or just getting too old for this ... :)

Comment: okay thank you for the example. How do you do the bend for only a portion of the cylinder though? then have it continue at the angle of bend end?  like with parameters (bend_start_y, bend_end_y, bend_amount)  is that still possible with this method? i noticed the entire cylinder is bending

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea That is too vague sketch an image (before / after) of what your parameters (should) mean (2D slice should suffice possibly XZ or YZ plane depend on how you bending ...)... Also is your topology sorted by height like mine? (menaing one of the index in the array of points is the height in ascendin order (or descending)

Comment: okay here is a sketch:)  https://imgur.com/a/P943tn0  yes the vertices in my array start with lowest and go to highest

Comment: Tyvm,  i am very close and pretty sure i understand how it works.  But i get this wide shape.  Any idea what could be going wrong here? https://codepen.io/funianrun/pen/OrYYwV

Comment: TY:) I applied all the changes and the shape is looking different.  Can you take a look at it now? https://codepen.io/funianrun/pen/OrYYwV  It's closer, but is kinda split in half (you can click and drag the cylinder to rotate it for a better view).  I also made a response to Edit3 here, where I detail all the changes https://pastebin.com/XRBywWFg .  I added more comments to the codepen too so it's more organized, and changed the variables' names so they exactly match Edit2

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea added `[edit4]` looks like you mess up the axises but only in the `PC` computation ... the rest looks OK

Comment: i changed it to X0 but still have the same look.  I was wondering at this section // transform system0 -> system1 of Edit2,  it seems like mid1 at mid1[j]=rotatex(mid1[j]-p,PC,a); and dir1 below it are set, but never used again in the rotation calculation?  Can we remove them?

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea no they are used for the computation of `P0X0Y0Z0` which you are still not doing. Without it would not be possible to bend your mesh more than once. Did you render the `mid` and `dir`? they should form a central axis of the shape. Also render the `PC` as a point if it si computed correctly. Also make sure you are passing your angles into `sin,cos` in correct units mine uses `[rad]` but some languages/libs uses `[deg]` instead.

Comment: now the cylinder is finally bending https://codepen.io/funianrun/pen/vbNrMX  but, it is a bit distorted, will check back with updates soon

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea at line 172: `rotatez(mid1_line.geometry.vertices[j],PC,a);` I think it should be `mid1_line.geometry.vertices[j]=rotatez(mid1_temp,PC,a);` and in line 194: `rotatez(slices[j][i],PC,a);` it should be `slices[j][i]=rotatez(point_temp,PC,a);` unless the return values from function or array access works in your language differently then I expect ... can you also add the coodinate system axises as RGB lines (X red) so we can see if the center is shifted in right direction ...

Comment: here it is with the coordinate system and coloring https://codepen.io/funianrun/pen/gqMJGy  , note, I did scale them by 100 to make them visable, i also added P0.y on ONLY for the drawing of axis.  In project  if I add P0.y before the shape get extremely distorted

Comment: also take a look at when i set the bend to effect the entire cylinder.  It seems like the bend is going opposite direction of the center of rotation, https://codepen.io/funianrun/pen/ZwONwJ

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea see [edit5] you have again not corresponding equations in the same parts of code. If I where you I would write all the corresponding lines of my code (or at leas in the parts where you are bugging) as comment and below it its port to your environment so you directly see what your code should do and easily check for mistakes. The different vector math API is quite misleading and from the looks of it for you too ...