# Algorithm for bending a series of vertices at an arbitrary angle?

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, geometry

I am looking for some information on how to "bend" an arbitrary list of points/vertices similar to the bend modifier you can find in typical 3D modelling programs.

I want to provide a list of points, a rotation focal point, and a "final angle."  For my purposes, I will always be saying "points at minimum y of the set will not change, points at maximum y will be rotated at the maximum angle, everything in between is interpolated."

Example Image of starting configuration and desired result, given a 90 degree rotation:

[image: img]

Can anyone suggest a resource that would explain how to go about this?  I'm prepared to code it (C++) but I'm wracking my brain on a concept that would make this work.  It would be easy to generate the vertices, but the application I'm writing this for takes in user-created content and needs to bend it.

(Edited to add: I don't need a miracle matrix or deep equation solution... if you say something like "for each vertex, do this" that's good enough to get the green checkmark)

Thanks!

Comment: If an image is crucial to the question, please post the image in the question, not a link to it.

Comment: this looks like very similar problem to this [How to bend a cylinder in three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54050883/2521214)

Comment: @Beta low rep users lack the ability to do so, IIRC.

Comment: @WillNess: Really? I don't see it on [the list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)...

Comment: @Beta I think I saw such complaints in the comments though  I'm not sure....

Comment: @Beta yes that is right low rep users can not post images .. .which is weird as images and code are usually crucial to questions ...

Comment: @Spektre: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be transforming a straight line to a circular arc, preserving distances between adjacent points.

So, if the point `A` is the one you want to hold constant, pick another point `B` to be the center of that circle. (The nearer `B` is to `A`, the more severe the bending.) Now for any point `C` you want to transform, break the vector `C-B` into the component parallel to `A-B` (call that component `R`) and the component perpendicular to it (call that `k`). The magnitude of `R` will be the radius of the circle you map `C` to, and you can transform the magnitude of 'k' into distance along that circle:

```
theta = |k|/|R|
C` = B + R cos(theta) + k|R|/|k| sin(theta)
```