# Mesh need to be deformed along a curve

Tags: c#, 3d, computational-geometry, mesh

I want to be able to extrude a mesh I have imported (obj file) along a path, the same way you would do it with [the curve + array modifier in blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRK8UMudejg&t=36s&ab_channel=RyanKingArt), [splines in unreal engine](https://youtu.be/RLc20gcc804?t=435), or godot's CGApolygon.

I am able to create linear array of mesh using geomtery4Sharp library. But when I try to blend the two mesh to fill the gap the mesh geometry weird.

Linear Array (5 mesh):
[image]

Blend two mesh:
[image]

Code I used for blending:

```
  var readOptions = ReadOptions.Defaults;
  readOptions.ReadMaterials = true;

  var meshBuilder = new DMesh3Builder();

  var result = g4.StandardMeshReader.ReadFile(this.objFile,
                                              readOptions,
                                              meshBuilder);

  if (result.code == IOCode.Ok)
  {
    var xOffset = 20;
    var mesh = meshBuilder.Meshes[0];

    var mesh2 = new DMesh3(mesh);
    MeshTransforms.Translate(mesh2, xOffset, 0,0);
    MeshTransforms.Rotate(mesh2, new Vector3f(0,0,0), Quaternionf.AxisAngleD(new Vector3f(0,1,0), 3));


    var cellSize = 64;

    var impMesh1 = this.meshToImplicitF(mesh,
                                        cellSize,
                                        0);

    var impMesh2 = this.meshToImplicitF(mesh2,
                                        cellSize,
                                        0);


    var blend = new ImplicitBlend3d();
    blend.A = impMesh1;
    blend.B = impMesh2;
    blend.Blend = 10;

    this.generateMeshF(blend,
                       cellSize,
                       @"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Bridge 1\Export\test_Blend.obj");
}
```

Any pointers or help how to achieve the same.

Comment: see [How to bend a cylinder in three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54050883/2521214) for some inspiration you just extrude instead of bending ...